# Incomplete ResultSet

Tags: jdbc, resultset, jtds

I have query similar to the one below that I run against SQL Server 2008

**SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER P WHERE CUSTOMERID >= '1-458-20100500' AND P.CUSTOMERID <= '153294-301-5000713'**

The number of records returned when I run this query in the sql studio is 29000+ records, where as when I run the same query using jdbc in my application the number of rows in the resultset is 4,500+. Snapshot of the data is below:

**Customer ID's**

1-458-20100500
100002-104-19831017
100005-029-19831024
XXX
XXX
145817-297-19981115
145821-298-19981025
145822-299-19981025

All the records starting from 100002-104-19831017 and 145817-297-19981115 is skipped. I know it has something to do with the CustomerId's and internal sql comparison. As an FYI, I am using jtds driver.  Also, if I exclude the very first customer(1-458-20100500) from being selected the resultset contains all the rows.

Will appreciate if someone can share their thoughts on why resultset is incomplete. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It might help if you posted your JDBC code too